# DrawingVisual Mouse Up Event

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mouseevent

I am working on a WPF MVVM application.  It has a custom canvas class inheriting from Canvas.  There is a window with one of these custom canvas placed (using XAML) and it's background colour set to Transaparent.  Graphics are drawn to the Canvas using DrawingVisuals to draw primitive shapes and add them as Visual children to the Visual tree.  This works and renders my shapes to the screen.

I have added a mouse up event to the Canvas in the Window code behind.  This fires when I click anywhere on the canvas except on the line of a drawn visual or on the coloured area of a filled shape.  To be clear:

- If I click outside the drawn shape i.e. on the background of the
  canvas it fires.
- If there is an unfilled rectangle and I click on the inside blank
  area then the mouse up fires.
- If I click on the rectangle's border line it does not.
- If I click inside a filled rectangle it does not.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx#providing_hit_testing_support
it appears like this should work though I am using the Canvas MouseUp event as it does not have a MouseLeftButtonUp event.  In the MS example they don't use a Canvas but talk about a "host container" but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

How can I get the events to fire when clicking on a DrawingVisual?  Why is the event surpressed when clicking inside a drawn area but not outside it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.  The canvas has a RootNode dependency property which the ViewModel sets.   The problem is when you add any children to a canvas then you need to call AddVisualChild(child) and AddLogicalChild(child).  I had to add a property changed callback to the dependency property so it could call the two methods to add them as visual and logical children otherwise it doesn't understand the parent child relationships which screws up user input.

Thanks for you time everyone.  Sorry if I never provided enough details.  It's a big app so was trying to include only relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be because `Canvas` is doing the hit testing for you, and thus mouse clicks are getting routed to the child visuals.

Can you try deriving from `FrameworkElement` instead. Is there some behaviour of Canvas that you need?

Comment: Changing my custom class to inherit from FrameworkElement instead seems to stop the events firing at all.

Comment: Yeah just gave that a try too and no events fire.  It's like when you have a Canvas with no background colour specified.  But Framework element doesn't have a background colour so I have to remove the XAML that sets that attribute.  The colour stuff could be unrelated though.

Comment: FrameworkElement is not intended to listen for events! it holds the role of layout participation, if you are interested in listening for events, you need to extend UIElement

Comment: @simo `FrameworkElement` is a `UIElement` and has all the same functionality (plus some more of its own). And `Canvas` is a `FrameworkElement` and so has all the functionality of both (plus some more of its own).

Answer (score 0):

You should read this article about routed event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx
And how routed event will cross the rectangle to get to the main canvas :)

Comment: I don't think that applies to DrawingVisuals since they don't inherit from UIElement or ContentElement so can't handle routed events.  Or so I thought anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subscribing to the PreviewMouseUp event as well as MouseLeftButtonUp on your parent Canvas? The above should work, but something in the visual tree is likely marking the event as Handled so it isn't propagating.

Handling Preview ensures you get the event first (as previews tunnel down, then events bubble up, but if any preview event is handled, no further events are bubbled).

There's a detailed overview here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx

In addition, if that fails, you can always try a class handler on the event (basically an override of the above behaviour): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx#AddingInstanceHandlersthatAreRaisedEvenWhenEventsareMarkedHandled

Comment: Thanks.  I tried PreviewmouseUp but it fires under the same circumstances as MouseUp.

Comment: I tried Adding a handler for handled events and it only fires under the same circumstances as the normal event which I guess suggests soemthing isn't marking the event as handled.

Comment: @AlanMacdonald Hmm ok, crazy stuff. Alright, here's a workaround for you. create another canvas directly over the top with the same width/height and set background to Transparent. Then subscribe to the mouse event of that. Yes i know, horrible but it should work. If it doesn't it tells you that DrawingVisual isn't stealing the mouse events at all, but something else in your application is ...

Comment: @AlanMacdonald don't you also have to put something in the Canvas to host DrawingVisuals? Ie: VisualCollection. Perhaps that is stealing the events. My point is something in the visual tree is over your canvas and taking the event. Have you tried using WPF Snoop to inspect the visual tree to see what its generating?